# How do I resolve a circular dependency between CPAN modules?

Tags: perl

Not able to install module HTTP::DAV::Browse, which has dependency ->Algorithm::C3.
Now issue is :-
there is a circular dependency between Algorithm::C3 & class::C3 modules!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examining the dependencies, I don't see any way for Algorithm::C3 to depend on Class::C3, indirectly or directly.  What version of perl are you using?  And what output are you seeing that makes you think there's a circular dependency?